# Click event doesn't fire when the softkeyboard is open on Android / Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, android-softkeyboard

I am developing a phonegap app (Cordova 3). Tested on Android, When I click a text input field, the softkeyboard opens. I have a submit button in the view. When I enter a text and then click the submit button, it doesn't runs the on click event, but rather get the focus back to the view.

Only when I click the `Done` button and then the 'submit' button, the click event for that particular button fires. How can I make the submit button run the click button event while the softkeyboard is open?

Comment: This plugin may help you: https://github.com/mklement0/phonegap-plugin-softkeyboard-android There is a callback-function that is fired when the board is closed.

Comment: How can it help solve the problem?

Comment: You could hide the button as long as the board is not dismissed and show the button when the board is being dismissed.